# Log off from Remote Desktop Session does not closing Session, showing the login screen again on Windows XP 32 Bit - SP2

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, 32-bit, gina

As per requirement we have written one custom GINA. I have observed one interesting behavior in **Windows XP 32 Bit(SP2)**. Customized GINA internally calls windows default Windows GINA (msgina.dll) and shows one extra window as per our requirement.

I used to do remote desktop to XP machine from my machine. After replacing Windows GINA with customized GINA I tried to log off from the XP Machine (I am Using Remote Desktop Connection to log in), Log off completes successfully (After showing saving your settings, Closing network connections etc) and I will get log in screen which we get during log on, this is not expected compared to other flavors of Windows OD.

Where as in other operating systems such as Windows XP 64 Bit/ Windows 2003 32/64 Bit even after replacing the Windows Gina with custom GINA remote desktop session closes after log off from the machine. I have tried installing Novell GINA on Windows XP 32 Bit but I have not find any issue with that.

I have Tried upgrading XP SP2 to SP3, still I am facing the same issue.

Has anyone else faced such issues when working with Windows GINA?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I had the same issues. Are you passing most of the functions through to msgina or do you do a lot of custom processing (and replacing the original code)?

My custom GINA was a very shallow wrapper of existing functionality and worked perfectly fine on Windows 2000, XP and 2003.

However, as to the differences in behavior: XP x64 is based on the Windows 2003 Server code base. So this could well explain some of the similarities between those and differences to "vanilla" XP.

Comment: Since no one else sees value in my answer, I'm going to delete it.